# Definition of axially symmetric surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading a paper and I don't understand what is the meaning of  axially symmetric surface.
I have been looking and all I have got is that an example is  a surface of revolution because of the symmetry with respect to the revolution axis.

I don't understand if the axis of geometry may be the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis, or the $z$-axis, or if any linear subspace or if any other coordinate not linear, for example, $\theta$.

I would appreciate any reference where I can read some definition.

Comment: Which paper are you reading?

Comment: Some paper about relativity, so the context is Minkowsky space time and polar coordinates, sorry if the question its so basic, just i did not know the definition and i have not found any

Answer (score 0):

The axis of symmetry could be any of the coordinate axes such that the $3$-dimensional surface of rotation has axial (rotational) symmetry about this axis.

More generally, if you have a surface with rotational symmetry, then you can re-position all three standard coordinate axes so that one of them ($x$-axis, $y$-axis, or $z$-axis) becomes its axis of rotation (this is done by changing coordinates to the function defining the surface).

Thus, an $\textbf{axially symmetric surface}$ is defined to be the surface generated by a (planar) curve rotated about the axis of rotation.

Here is a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.0021.pdf) on the study of axially symmetric surfaces, which you may find interesting.